# what wireless protocol does logitech m705 use

Tags: logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse

I understand its technology name is 2.4GHZ unifying, but I want to know if its any of n/g/ac protocols

basically I want to order it by amazon to israel and there are restrictions, so I must know what protocol does it use

Comment: Just walk to a computer shop in Israel. If they sell it (or any other logitech wireless mouse), then it's legal to use.

Comment: not so fast, sometimes you need a permit.

Answer (score 0):

Logitech's "Unifying Receiver" is proprietary and not directly using WiFi protocols. It's just using that frequency band because its usage is open for consumer devices. It's closely related to Bluetooth, yet it isn't compatible or interchangable.